# Backup power supply boost converter TPS61030

Tags: power-supply, boost

I'm developing a backup power supply using a supercapacitor and a  [TPS61030](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps61030.pdf) boost converter based on [this](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidu594/tidu594.pdf) Texas Instruments circuit design.
This is the circuit shown in the reference guide:  [image: boost converter]
and it is explained that the **VOUT** is set through the feedback resistors **R6**, **R9** and **R10**. When the **Vsys** is present, the voltage at the **LBI** pin is above the threshold and the pin **LBO** is at high impedance so the resistor **R9** is not affecting the others feedback resistors, setting the (so called in the guide) **Vout_re** to 4.5V, so lower than the **Vsys** after the **D1** diode. In the case **Vsys** disappears, the pin **LBO** is connected to **GND**, modifying the feedback network in such a way to obtain 5V at the output. You can find the calculation at page 5 of the reference guide. This is functional block diagram from the datasheet: 
[image: functional diagram] 
I don't understand why they are differentiating **VOUT** and **Vout_re**, because since the feedback resistors are used to set the **VOUT** voltage, those 4.5V should be also present at the output, lowering the value of the **Vout** when the **Vsys** is present. What I would expect, since this is a backup PS, is that as long as the **Vsys** is present, the boost converter goes in some kind of high impedance state, and not output 4.5V. I think I'm missing something, probably the IC is not outputting this voltage, but I cannot find a proof of that neither in the datasheet nor in the reference guide. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you naturally set the output to regulate at 4.5 volts and a slightly higher voltage is present (due to Vsys and D1), the regulator will immediately shut-down it's output stage in order to *try to* regulate to 4.5 volts. Clearly Vsys holds the output higher at 4.5 volts hence the output stage of the regulator shuts down.

> those 4.5V should be also present at the output, lowering the value of
>   the Vout when the Vsys is present

You have to remember that the output from this voltage regulator is not some kind of push-pull output that can force a lower voltage; it is a single series transistor between Vbat and Vout and will just go open-circuit when overdriven at its output.